# Python3 : AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I am getting the following error:

```
Python3 : AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'
```

for the line:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
```

I have tried installing `opencv-contrib-python` and uninstalling `opencv-python` and they didn't help get rid of this error. 
Any help appreciated!
Using Mac OSX,Python 3,opencv 3

Comment: can you show what you imported? (`from cv2 import cv2` perhaps?)

Comment: Although Mac osx is clearly not ubuntu - it won't be working for the same reasons.

Comment: check this link https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/